# Dlink DIR-868L stuck in recovery mode

Tags: router, dd-wrt, system-recovery

I had DD-WRT installed on my Dlink DIR-868L, however, after attempting to update to the Tomato OS I bricked my router.

Whenever I power on the router the power LED starts to blick ever ~1-2 sec. If I try the 30/30/30 reset or try to push and hold the reset button on power on it keeps blicking in the same interval.

I have also tried to manually set my PCs IP to 192.168.0.2/24, however, I don't get to the recovery page on 192.168.0.1 (my PC was the only device connected to the router).

I'm quite frustrated; does any of you have an idea what I could try to fix it?

Thanks for the help! Cheers

Comment: Is it responding to pings on 192.168.0.1? Set a static IP again, From the command prompt type "ping 192.168.0.1 -t". That should keep the attempts going, power the router off. Now hold in the reset button while powering it back up for about 10-15 seconds. Did you get any period of echo responses from the router?

Comment: I have already tried this; I just get "Destination host unreachable." 
And I noticed that the interval (of the power LED blinking) is shorter it is about ~1-2 sec

Answer (score 1):

You have bricked the router. The only option you have now is to purchase a USB-TTL adapter and reach the console by the headers on the router board. You can use this method to clear whatever happened in the nv_ram, and allow you to recover via the cli and tftp.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the certification. Is this the module you were referring to? https://www.amazon.de/SODIAL-USB-TTL-Konverter-Modul-eingebautem-CP2102/dp/B008RF73CS?SubscriptionId=AKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q&tag=duc03-21&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B008RF73CS

Comment: This looks identical to the one I have. The page for this isn't in my language, so I'm have trouble identifying the specs. I believe you can also use an Arduino or rasberry pi for this if you have one laying around.

Comment: I have a raspberry pi; to do happen to know a guide how to clear the nv_ram using the raspberry pi?

Comment: What's the revision number on the sticker? Is it A1 or B1?

Comment: revision number is B1